# Codeigniter output class doesn't contain http 429 status code

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-headers, http-status-code-429

I've been using codeigniter for development and making use of the output class (https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/output.html) to make it easy to send correct status codes, headers and json responses.

However, after trying to debug an issue I've had for a while, I realised that the set_status_header function implements the status codes in RFC 2616 (https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) but not the additional status codes defined in RFC 6585 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585). This means that I can't send a 429 (Too many requests) status code.

Is there an updated version of the output class that supports this or should I just use php's header() function to deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

Decided to use http_response_code() and still use the output class, so my code looks like this:

```
http_response_code(429);
return $this->output
    ->set_header("Retry-After: " . $resp['retry_after'])
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_output($json_result);
```

Which is fine, just a little annoying that it's different from the normal:

```
return $this->output
    ->set_status_header('401')
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_output($json_result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend core output class by creating MY_Output.php in application/core and override `set_status_header()`.

MY_Output.php

```
class MY_Output extends CI_Output {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function set_status_header($code = 200, $text = '') {
        // copied helper function set_status_header() code from system/core/Common.php
        if (is_cli())
        {
            return;
        }

        if (empty($code) OR ! is_numeric($code))
        {
            show_error('Status codes must be numeric', 500);
        }

        if (empty($text))
        {
            is_int($code) OR $code = (int) $code;
            // Add your status codes/text in this array below
            $stati = array(
                100 => 'Continue',
                101 => 'Switching Protocols',

                200 => 'OK',
                201 => 'Created',
                202 => 'Accepted',
                203 => 'Non-Authoritative Information',
                204 => 'No Content',
                205 => 'Reset Content',
                206 => 'Partial Content',

                300 => 'Multiple Choices',
                301 => 'Moved Permanently',
                302 => 'Found',
                303 => 'See Other',
                304 => 'Not Modified',
                305 => 'Use Proxy',
                307 => 'Temporary Redirect',

                400 => 'Bad Request',
                401 => 'Unauthorized',
                402 => 'Payment Required',
                403 => 'Forbidden',
                404 => 'Not Found',
                405 => 'Method Not Allowed',
                406 => 'Not Acceptable',
                407 => 'Proxy Authentication Required',
                408 => 'Request Timeout',
                409 => 'Conflict',
                410 => 'Gone',
                411 => 'Length Required',
                412 => 'Precondition Failed',
                413 => 'Request Entity Too Large',
                414 => 'Request-URI Too Long',
                415 => 'Unsupported Media Type',
                416 => 'Requested Range Not Satisfiable',
                417 => 'Expectation Failed',
                422 => 'Unprocessable Entity',
                429 => 'Too Many Requests',

                500 => 'Internal Server Error',
                501 => 'Not Implemented',
                502 => 'Bad Gateway',
                503 => 'Service Unavailable',
                504 => 'Gateway Timeout',
                505 => 'HTTP Version Not Supported'
            );

            if (isset($stati[$code]))
            {
                $text = $stati[$code];
            }
            else
            {
                show_error('No status text available. Please check your status code number or supply your own message text.', 500);
            }
        }

        if (strpos(PHP_SAPI, 'cgi') === 0)
        {
            header('Status: '.$code.' '.$text, TRUE);
        }
        else
        {
            $server_protocol = isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] : 'HTTP/1.1';
            header($server_protocol.' '.$code.' '.$text, TRUE, $code);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```